# Simple game of hangman with two character arrays. They get six tries. First user enters a word the second user guesses the word through _ blanks

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HangmanGame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

    int guesses = 0;
```

//Do I really need this part?

```
    //Ask the user to enter a word and store it into an array
    System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
    String wordToGuess = kybd.next();
    char[] word = wordToGuess.toCharArray();
    char[] underscore = new char[wordToGuess.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
      underscore[i] = '_';
    }

    System.out.println("You have 6 tries to guess the word:");
    for ( int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
      System.out.println(" " + underscore[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");
    char guess = kybd.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (guess == word[i]) {
        underscore[i] = guess;
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

// I've gotten a little lost here.

I know this is not right at all but I'm hoping for some tips. Thanks so much!!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to finish this code because I know its not nearly done.

Comment: so where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangmanGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
        String wordToGuess = kybd.next();
        char[] underscore = new char[wordToGuess.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
          underscore[i] = '_';
        }




        int wordLenToGuess = wordToGuess.length();
        int unsuccessfulTries = 6;

        while(wordLenToGuess >0 && unsuccessfulTries >0 ){
            System.out.println();
            for ( int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
              System.out.print(" " + underscore[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("You have " +unsuccessfulTries+ " tries to make a guess");
            System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");
            //kybd.nextLine();
            char guess = kybd.next().charAt(0);
            boolean iscorrect = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < underscore.length; i++) {
                if(wordToGuess.charAt(i) == guess)
                {
                    underscore[i] = guess;
                    wordLenToGuess--;
                    iscorrect = true;
                }
            }

            if(!iscorrect)
                unsuccessfulTries--;
        }

        if(wordLenToGuess == 0)
            System.out.println("YOU WIN!! :)");
        else System.out.println("Sorry! You Lose :(");

    }

}
```

Algorithm:
Keep trying till either entire word is guessed or 6 incorrect tries.

If correct letter is guessed, fill in the blanks '_' else decrement the number of tries

Exit loop when either entire word is guessed or all 6 tries are used up.

Inform user if he wins or loses.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things that need to be addressed here include giving the user the option to guess either a letter or a word, having the game go on as long as the user has not yet guessed the word yet, and checking to see if the user guessed a letter he or she has already guessed (this last thing is optional but is good practice for error checking). Think about the condition that will keep the game going. The game won't end until the user guessed 6 times or managed to successfully guess the word. To check these conditions after each guess, we can use a while loop. To see if the user guessed the word correctly, we can use a boolean variable to keep track of this,

```
boolean wordHasBeenGuessed = false;
while(!wordHasBeenGuessed && guesses < 6)
//this loop reads "while the word has not been guessed yet and the user has not exceeded 6 guesses
```

To give the user the option to guess either a letter or a word, we need to present two scenarios using if statements,

```
System.out.println("Would you like to guess a letter or a word?");
String type = kybd.next();
if(type.toLowerCase().equals("letter"){
//do stuff to deal with this case here
}
else{
//do stuff to deal with this case here
}//of course this part can be customized anyway you'd like
```

In the end, it should look something like this,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HangmanGame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

    int guesses = 0;


    //Ask the user to enter a word and store it into an array
    System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
    String wordToGuess = kybd.next();
    char[] word = wordToGuess.toCharArray();
    char[] underscore = new char[wordToGuess.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
      underscore[i] = '_';
    }
    boolean wordHasBeenGuessed = false;
    int numOfLettersFound = 0;
    while(!wordHasBeenGuessed && guesses < 6){
         System.out.println("You have " + (6-guesses) + " tries to guess the word:");

         for ( int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
              System.out.print(" " + underscore[i] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println("Would you like to guess a letter or a word?");
         String type = kybd.next();
         if(type.toLowerCase().equals(letter)){
              System.out.println("Enter your guess");
              char guess = kybd.next();
                  for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
                      if (guess == word[i]) {
                          underscore[i] = guess;
                          numOfLettersFound++;
                      }
                  }
              if(numOfLettersFound == wordToGuess.length()){
                  wordHasBeenGuessed = true;
              }
         }
         else{
              System.out.println("Enter your guess");
              String answer = kybd.next();
              if(answer.eqauls(wordToGuess){
                  wordHasBeenGuessed = true;
              }
         }
         guesses++;
     }
     //after the while loop is finished, tell the user whether or not he/she has won or not
     if(wordHasBeenGuessed){
         System.out.println("You won");
     }
     else{
         System.out.println("You lost");
     }
  }
```

}

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.